# How to print fields manually

Tags: debugging

I am using print module. I am also using devel module. In print.tpl.php file, I see a php code that prints the content as `print $content.` I don't want to print the entire content. I think content is an array. How can I print manually some fields from the content variable using the devel module or in php?

Thanks.
D

---

  1.

> print render($content['field_machine_name']);

Get this error:
 Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference in /..sites/all/modules/print/print.tpl.php on line 100

2. > php  print $content['field_machine_name'];

I get left error only (<)

  3.

> print $fields['field_vehicle_options']->content;

I get completely blank

---

I am using bartik 7.22.

1. themes > bartik > template.php

Added the below function.

```
function bartik_preprocess_print(&$vars, $hook) {

// Global node.
$node = $vars['node'];

// Create a var and render using field_view_value
$vars['test'] = field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_price', $node->field_price[$node->language][0]);

}
```

2. themes > bartik > template > print.tpl.php

I added:
print render($test);

3. I went to my page
   http://bettylist.com/ac/node/12 > clicked printer friendly link >
   I did not see the value of variable.

In print.tpl.php, what works:

```
print $content; //I GET CONTENT IN PRINT PAGE
print dsm($title); // I GET VALUE OF TITLE IN PRINT PAGE
```

Please advise.
Thanks,
D

---

It worked. I have added one more variable as below:

```
function bartik_preprocess_print(&$vars, $hook) {

// Global node.
$node = $vars['node'];

// Create a var and render using field_view_value
$vars['price'] = field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_price', $node->field_price[$node->language][0]);


// Create a var and render using field_view_value
$vars['vehicleOption1'] = field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_vehicle_option_1', $node->field_vehicle_option_1[$node->language][0]);

}
```

In print.tpl.php, I added

```
print render($test);
print render($vehicleOption1);
```

But I am only getting the value of the last variable $vars'vehicleOption1'.

Please advise.

Comment: It worked after I cleared the cache. Thank you so so much. You are great. Now, if I want 10 variables to print, I have to do the same for the 10 variables. That mean, I have to declare 10 variables in template and then print it in print.tpl.php? Thanks again.

Comment: yes, you need to declare all variables you want in **template.php** and than use them in **print.tpl.php** file.

Comment: I think I am not sure how to declare. Can you please see my above message and see what I did wrong?

Comment: In your update above you declared two variables in **template.php** file, `price` and `vehicleOption1`, but you didn't declare variable `test` so you couldn't use it (as you did in your **print.tpl.php** file).

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
<?php print render($content['your_field_name']); ?>
```

This should print the field you want.

Change `'your_field_name'` with machine name of the desired field.

You can install and enable [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module and add this:

```
<?php dsm($node); ?>
<?php dsm($content); ?>
```

in your `print.tpl.php` file. You will see all $node and content fields.

## UPDATE

Also, you can add this function in your **template.php** file:

```
/**
  * Renders the content of the print page using the theme api.
  */
function THEME_preprocess_print(&$vars, $hook) {

// Global node.
$node = $vars['node'];

// Create a var and render using field_view_value
$vars['any_variable'] = field_view_value('node', $node, 'your_field_name', $node->your_field_name[$node->language][0]);

}
```

Replace `THEME` with your theme name, `any_variable` with any name you want for this variable and `your_field_name` with machine name of your field.

After this you can render your field in **print.tpl.php** file like this:

```
<?php print render($any_variable); ?>
```

Again, change `any_variable` with the name you choose for this variable in function from **template.php** file.

Comment: 1. 

<?php
 print render($content['field_machine_name']); 
?>

Get this error:
 Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference in /..sites/all/modules/print/print.tpl.php on line 100                     

2. 

<?php
 print $content['field_machine_name']; 
?>

I get left error only (<)

3. 

<?php
 print $fields['field_vehicle_options']->content; 
?>

I get completely blank.

Comment: @Drupol see update in my answer...